# With PGFPlots: How to manually enter ticks as fractions?

Tags: pgfplots

We can **display** tick labels as fractions by setting:

`xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/frac}`

However, *how can we manually enter the tick points as fractions?*

Just using `xtick={0,2/3,1}` does not work see, the MWE below.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.5}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/frac},
 domain=0:1,
 samples=9,
 xtick={0,2/3,1} ]
 \addplot { x };
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PGFPlots doesn't parse the expressions given in the `xtick` list. You can define your own key that does this and generates the list used for the tick labels.

Note that in order to get `2/3` to print correctly, you need to use `/pgf/number format/frac shift=2` (or `1`) to decrease the tolerance of the algorithm.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{width=9cm,compat=1.5}

 \makeatletter
 \pgfplotsset{
    xtick parsed/.code={
        \c@pgf@counta 0\relax
        \foreach \x in {#1} {
            \pgfmathparse{\x}
            \ifnum\c@pgf@counta=0
                \xdef\pgfplots@xtick{\pgfmathresult}
            \else
                \xdef\pgfplots@xtick{\pgfplots@xtick,\pgfmathresult}
            \fi
            \global\advance\c@pgf@counta 1\relax
        }
    }
 } 
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/frac, /pgf/number format/frac shift=2},
 domain=0:1,
 samples=9,
 xtick parsed={0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}]
 \addplot { x };
 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `\sfrac{1}{2}` of package `xfrac`?