# fairly specific cartesian graph help

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have been trying for an hour or two to  draw a TikZ plot with varied results. I am trying to draw a plot whose x axis has ticks for each x unit `n*(1)` and each y unit `n*($\sqrt{-5}$)`. I then need to draw a circle, centered at `(0,0)` with arbitrary length, labeled `n`.

I have drawn a fairly crude version of what I would like to insert into my tex file. It is very important that the axis is skewed to reflect this strange imaginary space. For instance the number `2 + 2 \sqrt{5}` would be a dot exactly on the dashed grey grid in the second position on both axes.

My biggest problems are skewing the axis and labeling this new version with the correct numbers. Also, I am having trouble drawing the circle because sqrt fxn is not recognized in tikz setting.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to see what you've done so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution using [PGFPlots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) parsed ticks (from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187120/14589) Jake's answer) and a PGF macro to define the complex number.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \makeatletter
 \pgfplotsset{
    ytick parsed/.code={
        \c@pgf@counta 0\relax
        \foreach \y in {#1} {
            \pgfmathparse{\y}
            \ifnum\c@pgf@counta=0
            \xdef\pgfplots@ytick{\pgfmathresult}
            \else
            \xdef\pgfplots@ytick{\pgfplots@ytick,\pgfmathresult}
            \fi
            \global\advance\c@pgf@counta 1\relax
        }
    }
 } 
 \makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\re}{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\im}{2*sqrt(5)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{sqrt(\re^2 + \im^2)}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal,
                     xlabel=$\Re(z)$,
                     ylabel=$\Im(z)$,
                     axis lines=middle,
                     grid=major,
                     grid style=dashed,
                     xmin=-6,xmax=6,
                     xtick={-6,...,6},
                     ymin=-6,ymax=6,
                     ytick parsed={-2*sqrt(5), -sqrt(5), sqrt(5),  2*sqrt(5)},
                     yticklabels={$-2\sqrt{5}$, $-\sqrt{5}$, $\sqrt{5}$,  $2\sqrt{5}$}]
        \addplot[very thick, MediumPurple!50, domain=0:360, samples=100, variable=\t] ({\n*cos(t)},{\n*sin(t)});
        \draw[|-|, MediumOrchid, very thick] (axis cs:0,0) -- node[left,black] {\small n} (axis cs:\re,\im);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use `pgfplots`, since it makes it easy to draw coordinate axes and the grid.  There is also an option `unit vector ratio` for the aspect ratio ("skew?").  I don't know if it's possible to add the square root of 5 there as a formula as well.  Elsewhere, `5^0.5` seems to work, but `sqrt(5)` also seems to work at most places.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    unit vector ratio={1 2.236068},
    xmin=-4.5,xmax=4.5,
    ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,
    xtick={-4,...,4},
    yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\cdot\sqrt{-5}$},
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={dashed}
    ]
    \draw[lightgray] (axis cs:0,0) circle [x radius={(5)^0.5*1.3},y radius=1.3];
    \draw[purple,|-|] (0,0) -- node[left] {$n$} ({1.3*(5/2)^0.5},{1.3*1/(2^0.5)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the final picture]